# TCPDF reports "Undefined index: style" on single <hr> tag

Tags: php, tcpdf

A simple

```
$pdf->writeHTML("<hr>", true, false, false, false, '');
```

which did work when last tested (a few versions of TCPDF ago), now results in "Undefined index: style".

The relevant code from the TCPDF sources is

```
case 'hr': {
    if ((isset($tag['height'])) AND ($tag['height'] != '')) {
        $hrHeight = $this->getHTMLUnitToUnits($tag['height'], 1, 'px');
    } else {
        $hrHeight = $this->GetLineWidth();
    }
    $this->addHTMLVertSpace($hbz, max($hb, ($hrHeight / 2)), $cell, $firsttag);
    $x = $this->GetX();
    $y = $this->GetY();
    $wtmp = $this->w - $this->lMargin - $this->rMargin;
    if ($cell) {
        $wtmp -= ($this->cell_padding['L'] + $this->cell_padding['R']);
    }
    if ((isset($tag['width'])) AND ($tag['width'] != '')) {
        $hrWidth = $this->getHTMLUnitToUnits($tag['width'], $wtmp, 'px');
    } else {
        $hrWidth = $wtmp;
    }
    $prevlinewidth = $this->GetLineWidth();

    $this->SetLineWidth($hrHeight);
        $lineStyle = array(
        'color' => $tag['fgcolor'],
        'cap'   => $tag['style']['cap'], // Error thrown here.
        'join'  => $tag['style']['join'],
        'dash'  => $tag['style']['dash'],
        'phase' => $tag['style']['phase'],
    );

    $lineStyle = array_filter($lineStyle);

    $this->Line($x, $y, $x + $hrWidth, $y, $lineStyle);
    $this->SetLineWidth($prevlinewidth);
    $this->addHTMLVertSpace(max($hbc, ($hrHeight / 2)), 0, $cell, !isset($dom[($key + 1)]));
    break;
```

The value of `$tag` is

```
Array
(
    [elkey] => 0
    [tag] => 1
    [value] => hr
    [block] => 1
    [opening] => 1
    [parent] => 0
    [self] => 1
    [hide] => 
    [fontname] => dejavusans
    [fontstyle] => 
    [fontsize] => 10
    [font-stretch] => 100
    [letter-spacing] => 0
    [stroke] => 0
    [fill] => 1
    [clip] => 
    [line-height] => 1.25
    [bgcolor] => 
    [fgcolor] => Array
        (
            [R] => 0
            [G] => 0
            [B] => 0
        )

    [strokecolor] => Array
        (
            [R] => 0
            [G] => 0
            [B] => 0
        )

    [align] => 
    [listtype] => 
    [text-indent] => 0
    [text-transform] => 
    [border] => Array
        (
        )

    [dir] => ltr
    [attribute] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

As can be seen, there is no `style` key. Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug in TCPDF? How can I work around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first glance, it might be a bug in TCPDF indeed. See how they run an [`array_filter()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) just after to filter out the empty values. Such "Undefined index" errors trigger `E_notice` errors, which are left out in many PHP configurations.

Comment: I signed into GitHub to report an issue, and found it already reported: https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF/issues/347

Comment: Looks like it's already been fixed, but the fix hasn't hit stable yet. I could have just waited and this bug would have fixed itself.

Answer (score 0):

As say TRiG, it's a bug in TCPDF. If you have a look at the code, you'll see that TCPDF check if his parameters are existing, using isset. In the case of *hr* the isset test is missing for style (look line 18902 of version 6.4.1 and you'll see such a test for height)
To avoid the problem you have 4 options:

1. use older TCPDF version which can't style *hr*
2. wait new version update
3. add an isset test in the code a bit like that:

   ```
            // Line 18922
            $a = isset($tag['style']['cap']);
            if ($a== false)
            {
                // Add here the default value you want
                $tag['style']['cap'] = "";
                $tag['style']['join'] = "";
                $tag['style']['dash'] = "";
                $tag['style']['phase'] = "";
            }
            // The TCPDF code, using the values
            $lineStyle = array(
                'color' => $tag['fgcolor'],
                'cap'   => $tag['style']['cap'],
                'join'  => $tag['style']['join'],
                'dash'  => $tag['style']['dash'],
                'phase' => $tag['style']['phase'],
            );
   ```
4. Add a default style for *hr* at bottom of your HTML (easy solution!)